# Unable to record voice calls on Android 12

Tags: android

```
recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
           setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
           setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
           setOutputFile(fileName)
           setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
           registerAudioRecordingCallback(executor,object:
               AudioManager.AudioRecordingCallback() {

               override fun onRecordingConfigChanged(configs: MutableList<AudioRecordingConfiguration>?) {
                   super.onRecordingConfigChanged(configs)
                   configs?:return

                   configs.forEach {

                       LogUtil.d("isClientSilenced=${it.isClientSilenced} \n" +
                               "devices=$${it.audioDevice.address} \n" +
                               "effect=${it.effects.size} \n" +
                               "format=${it.format} \n" +
                               "audioSource=${it.audioSource}")
                   }

               }
           })
           try {
               prepare()
           } catch (e: IOException) {
               LogUtil.d("prepare() failed")
           }
           LogUtil.d("start record")
           start()
       }
```

The isClientSilenced method always returns true during voice calls, even if you are using AccessibilityService

to record voice calls

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I discovered that I must use the VOICE_RECOGNITION mode, and recording calls is only possible when not using headphones.
[image]